# How to figure out all possible pairs of numbers with a HCF?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The product of two numbers is $13005$ and their HCF is $17$. Find all possible pairs of numbers.

I've done the first part of the question but I'm stuck on how to find all possible pairs of numbers. Is there any easy way to find all possible pairs of numbers with their HCF being $17$?

The number I'm trying to find all the combinations of is $765$

Please make it really simple for me as I struggle to understand things when its written in complex algebra form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking for two numbers, of the form $X = \frac{a}{d}, Y = \frac{b}{d}$ that are relatively prime, where $d = 17$.  Further, since $(ab) = 13005$, then $$XY = \frac{13005}{(17)^2} = 45.$$  In general, to solve : $X,Y$ relatively prime, $(XY) = n$, take the prime factorization of  $n$, in the format $$(p_1)^{(\alpha_1)} \times \cdots \times (p_r)^{(\alpha_r)}.$$  Arbitrarily assigning $(p_1)^{(\alpha_1)}$ to $X$, there are $2^{(r-1)}$ ways of distributing the other prime factors, so that $(X,Y)$ are  relatively prime and $(XY) = n.$

Comment: im trying to figure out all the possible combinations of 765, sorry I worded that wring

Comment: @user2261923 i dont really understand what you're saying, as I commented I don't really get complex algebra

Comment: This is complicated.  I am unsure whether your reputation of $(11)$ is large enough for a chat room.  I will try to set one up and provide a link.  If it works, then we can review my comment step by step.  If not, then we will have to review my comment as  a series of back and forth comments on this webpage.  Please *stay tuned*.

Comment: Alternatively, do you understand the answer of EspeciallyLime?  If so, then we do not need to chat.  Please advise.

Comment: i dont really understand it but i don't really have time to do that now, I've got a maths exam in 5 minutes and I don't know if were going to be able to do it in that time

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ab=13005=45\times17^2$. Since $17$ is a common factor, we must have $a=17c$ and $b=17d$, where $cd=45$. Since it is the highest common factor, we need $c$ and $d$ to not have a common factor (if they have a common factor $h$ then $17h$ is a common factor of $a$ and $b$). How can you factorise $45=3^2\times 5$ so that the two factors are coprime?

Answer (score 0):

$13005=3^2\times 5\times 17^2$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\Large{17\times}&  & \Huge{\times} & \Large{17\times} &  \\ \hline
& 3\times 3\times 5 & & & 1 & & Yes\\ \hline
 &  3\times 3 & & & 5 & & Yes\\ \hline
 & 3\times 5 & & & 3 & & No\\ \hline
\end{array}